# AsyncStorage not working properly when saving multiple items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a main screen where you can see multiple items displayed in card form you can access an item by pressing it to see its details, on the details screen I added a bookmark option that save the item using async storage, you can also check the saved items on a different screen called savedItems screen.

The problem is :

- when i bookmark an item it get saved properly and i can go to the savedItems screen and find it there, but some times i have to reload the app for the item to appear on the savedItems screen why is that ?
- if i book multiple items they all get saved ( on console.log ) but only the last one appears for some reason i never get more then one item displayed on the SavedItems screen

Bellow is snippets of the code used to book mark ( saved an item on its details screen )

Details.js

```
const DetailScreen = (props) => {
  const [saved, setSaved] = useState([]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(props.route.params);
  const onSave = (item) => {
    const newItems = [...saved, item];

    setSaved(newItems);

    const items = JSON.stringify(newItems);

    SaveItem("saved", items).then((res) => {
      console.log("saved", res);
    });
  };

  const goToDetails = () => {
    setSaved([]);
    props.navigation.navigate("SaveScreen");
  };
  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
  const { data } = props.route.params; // this returns the data from each article

  //ReadItem("saved").then((res) => console.log(res));
  return (
  <TouchableOpacity
...
                onPress={() => {
                  onSave(data);
                }}
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="bookmark"
                  size={35}
                  color={colors.shade2}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

SaveScreen.js

```
export default class Details extends Component {
  
  state = {
    saved: [],
  };

  removeItem = () => {
    DeleteItem("saved")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          saved: [],
        });
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    ReadItem("saved")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          const saved = JSON.parse(res);
          this.setState({
            saved: saved,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => console.warn(e));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          data={this.state.saved}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <TouchableScale
                activeScale={0.9}
                tension={50}
                friction={7}
                useNativeDriver
                onPress={() =>
                  this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailScreen", { data: item })
                }
              >
                <Card item={item} />
              </TouchableScale>
            );
          }}
        />

        {this.state.saved.length > 0 && (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.removeItem} style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.save}>Remove Key</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

the code used to save data using async storage

Dbhelper.js

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

export const SaveItem = async (key, value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    console.log("saved");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

export const ReadItem = async (key) => {
  try {
    var result = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
};

export function MultiRead(key, onResponse, onFailure) {
  try {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(key).then((values) => {
      let responseMap = new Map();
      values.map((result, i, data) => {
        let key = data[i][0];
        let value = data[i][1];
        responseMap.set(key, value);
      });
      onResponse(responseMap);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    onFailure(error);
  }
}

export async function DeleteItem(key) {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
    return true;
  } catch (exception) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i book multiple items they all get saved ( on console.log ) but only the last one appears for some reason i never get more then one item displayed on the SavedItems screen

I think the problem is when you save new item you remove old items. You have to read old items when you mount `DetailScreen`. Or you can read items inside onSave method. It's more safety. It depends your application architecture

```js
const DetailScreen = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(props.route.params);
  
  const onSave = (item) => {
    let saved = [];

    ReadItem("saved")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          saved = JSON.parse(res);
        }

        const newItems = [...saved, item];
        const items = JSON.stringify(newItems);

        SaveItem("saved", items).then((res) => {
          console.log("saved", res);
        });
      })
      .catch((e) => console.warn(e));
  };


  const goToDetails = () => {
    setSaved([]);
    props.navigation.navigate("SaveScreen");
  };
  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
  const { data } = props.route.params; // this returns the data from each article

  //ReadItem("saved").then((res) => console.log(res));
  return (
  <TouchableOpacity
...
                onPress={() => {
                  onSave(data);
                }}
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="bookmark"
                  size={35}
                  color={colors.shade2}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

> when i bookmark an item it get saved properly and i can go to the savedItems screen and find it there, but some times i have to reload the app for the item to appear on the savedItems screen why is that ?

I have only one idea why it may happens. In some cases, you don't unmount `SaveScreen`. When you return to the `SaveScreen` componentDidMount is not called. Just try to add console.log to componentDidMount and when you reproduce this behavior if console.log is missed it means you `SaveScreen` wasn't unmounted

To handle all cases you can try to do that:

```js
export default class Details extends Component {
  
  state = {
    saved: [],
  };

  removeItem = () => {
    DeleteItem("saved")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          saved: [],
        });
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.readItems();
    this.unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', this.readItems);
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  readItems = () => {
    ReadItem("saved")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          const saved = JSON.parse(res);
          this.setState({
            saved: saved,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => console.warn(e));
  }

  render() { ... }
}
```

Comment: hello , thank you for your responose , as for my first question am not exactly sure where and how to call the usecallback can you please elaborate on that i never use them before , as for the second reply to my question i added a console.log to componentDidMount and it was missed when the behaviour was reproduced exactly like you mentioned , how can unmount the **SaveScreen**.

Comment: @Felix I've updated example, how you can Read Items right inside onSave method. It's the most safety way

Comment: **how can unmount the SaveScreen** It depends from your router. I think you open SaveScreen like StackNavigator and the problem reproduce when you don't close this screen and open one more over the SaveScreen. I recommend you to listen event willMount and read items on it. I will update my answer

Comment: you are a life saver, thank you for your anwser it was clear and straight to the point